# Mongodb creating copy of object

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Each time I use node app.js to start the server a new copy of the same object is created in database . In my code below it creates the test blog as many number of times as the node app.js is used to start the server .How can I fix this ?

```
var express    = require("express"),
    mongoose   = require("mongoose"),
    bodyParser = require("body-parser"),
    app        = express();

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/blog_app', {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

var blogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    image: String,
    body: String,
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

var Blog = mongoose.model("Blog", blogSchema);

Blog.create({
    title: "Test Blog",
    image: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494256997604-768d1f608cac?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2202&q=80",
    body: "This is a test app."
});


// INDEX route
app.get("/", function(req, res){
        res.redirect("/blogs");
});
app.get("/blogs", function(req, res){
        // res.render("index");
        Blog.find({}, function(err, blogs){
            if(err){
                console.log("ERROR!");
            } else {
                res.render("index", {blogs: blogs});
            }
        })
});



app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("SERVER HAS STARTED!");
});
```

> use blog_app
>   switched to db blog_app
>   db.blogs.find()
>   { "_id" : ObjectId("5dc2a990cebaeb07d43653ac"), "title" : "Test Blog", "image" : "https://unsplash.com/photos/-GzyUGKhjBY", "body" : "This is a test
>   app.", "date" : ISODate("2019-11-06T11:08:00.162Z"), "__v" : 0 }
>   { "_id" : ObjectId("5dc2aad48d1865088eed3881"), "title" : "Test Blog", "image" : "https://unsplash.com/photos/-GzyUGKhjBY", "body" : "This is a test
>   app.", "date" : ISODate("2019-11-06T11:13:24.344Z"), "__v" : 0 }
>   { "_id" : ObjectId("5dc2ae3f1f12100a748fdbb6"), "title" : "Test Blog", "image" : "https://unsplash.com/photos/-GzyUGKhjBY", "body" : "This is a test
>   app.", "date" : ISODate("2019-11-06T11:27:59.182Z"), "__v" : 0 }
>   { "_id" : ObjectId("5dc2ced6dbd5e902487e3241"), "title" : "Test Blog", "image" : "https://unsplash.com/photos/-GzyUGKhjBY", "body" : "This is a test
>   app.", "date" : ISODate("2019-11-06T13:47:02.818Z"), "__v" : 0 }
>   { "_id" : ObjectId("5dc2cf09a3052102541f30a9"), "title" : "Test Blog", "image" : "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494256997604-768d1f608cac?ixlib=
>   rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2202&q=80", "body" : "This is a test app.", "date" : ISODate("2019-11-06T13:47:53.972Z"), "
>   __v" : 0 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you have these lines in your code, it creates `Test Blog` on each application run:

```js
Blog.create({
    title: "Test Blog",
    image: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494256997604-768d1f608cac?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2202&q=80",
    body: "This is a test app."
});
```

If you want to create `Test Blog` record exactly once you better use [Model.findOneAndUpdate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) with `options.upsert = true`. It will find record and update it, or will create new one if record hasn't been found.

```js
Blog.findOneAndUpdate({name: "Test Blog"}, {
    title: "Test Blog",
    image: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494256997604-768d1f608cac?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2202&q=80",
    body: "This is a test app."
}, {upsert: true});
```